# TeamCity vs MSBuild command line

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I have a `.csproj` file which behaves differently when I build it in TeamCity compared to when I build it via the `msbuild.exe` executable.  If I knew *why*, I could try and fix it, but I've run out of ideas.

**Command line:** (formatted for readability)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe" 
    Web\MyProject\MyProject.csproj 
    /p:Configuration=Dev;PublishProfile=Dev.pubxml;OutputPath="bin\\";DeployOnBuild=true 
    /t:Package
```

**TeamCity build step:** (as it shows up in the metarunner, although I get the same behavior when treating it as a regular build step, and I've removed the `dotNetCoverage` parameters)

```
  <runner name="Package Service" type="MSBuild">
    <parameters>
      <param name="build-file-path" value="Web/MyProject/MyProject.csproj" />
      <param name="msbuild_version" value="12.0" />
      <param name="run-platform" value="x86" />
      <param name="msbuild.prop.Configuration" value="Dev" />
      <param name="msbuild.prop.DeployOnBuild" value="true" />
      <param name="msbuild.prop.PublishProfile" value="Dev.pubxml" />
      <param name="msbuild.prop.OutputPath" value="bin\\" />
      <param name="msbuild.prop.Platform" value="AnyCPU" />
      <param name="targets" value="Package" />
      <param name="teamcity.step.mode" value="default" />
      <param name="toolsVersion" value="12.0" />
    </parameters>
  </runner>
```

**What's the difference between these?**

The behavior I'm seeing is that an assembly on which MyProject.csproj depends (but which doesn't have the "Dev" build configuration) will build just fine with msbuild, but will fail with TeamCity (version 9.1.1).

Specifically, both methods will start with the task `ValidateGlobalPackageSetting`, but TeamCity then goes on to `ResolveProjectReferences` while msbuild goes on to `CollectFilesFromIntermediateAssembly`.

---

Having created diagnostic logs from msbuild for both methods, I found my problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

The teamcity log has `_DeployOnBuild = False`, but my msbuild log has `_DeployOnBuild = true`.  That would definitely explain the differences in behavior I'm seeing, but I don't have a clue why TeamCity is ignoring the `msbuild.prop.DeployOnBuild` property.

Comment: It's probably not the issue, but on the off chance... your toolsVersion is explicitly specified as 12 in the TeamCity settings, but not at all in the msbuild line, and in that case I think it'll just use what's specified in the project file.

Comment: @Nanhydrin - Good thought.  I actually did try explicitly specifying it after I made this post, and got the same behavior.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [asked this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-42821) on the offical Jetbrains tracking system and got an answer.

Apparently, TeamCity doesn't support arbitrary `msbuild.prop.*` arguments the way I expected it to.  The only two that it supports are `Configuration` and `Platform`.  For the rest, I needed to add this line:

```
<param name="runnerArgs" value="/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=%Configuration%.pubxml;OutputPath=&quot;bin\\&quot; />
```